# Cups - Possible DDoS and Broken Pipe (errno=32)

Tags: linux, cups

I am running a Cups Server on IPPS with a valid Letsencrypt Cert.
For the past months it worked well for clients with different OS (Win7-10, Mac, Linux)

They are all using the same universal Post Script Driver.

For the past few days however i have a client that opens a lot of connections (sample log below) triggering my *MaxClientsPerHost 80* Limit. About 2-5 connections per second are opened from one IP/Client.

As a result, when the clients tries to print sth it does happen with a high delay.

We tried reinstalling the client machine/drivers. Deleting and re-adding the Printer but to no avail.

An extensive google research yielded no hints as to why this happens.

So in hope of finding someone with a similar problem/deep cups knowledge i post my configuration below.

**Edit for Printer Configuration/Info**

- The Printer runs on Debian 10.
- Uses *cups-pdf* as printer wrapped with *tea4cups* - It will output a simple *.ps file*
- It requires authentication which is correctly configured and working on the client
- It is of no importance if there are already jobs in the queue
- All clients use the same driver

Any hints very welcome.

**Relevant Error Line: (from log below)**

```
cupsdReadClient: error=32, used=0, state=HTTP_STATE_WAITING, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODING_LENGTH, data_remaining=0, request=(nil)(), file=-1
```

**Sample Log**

```
D [19/Feb/2020:12:43:18 +0100] [Client 29] Server address is "YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY".
D [19/Feb/2020:12:43:18 +0100] [Client 29] Accepted from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:63298 (IPv4)
D [19/Feb/2020:12:43:18 +0100] [Client 29] Waiting for request.
d [19/Feb/2020:12:43:18 +0100] [Client 29] cupsdReadClient: error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_STATE_WAITING, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODING_LENGTH, data_remaining=0, request=(nil)(), file=-1
d [19/Feb/2020:12:43:18 +0100] [Client 29] Saw first byte 16, auto-negotiating SSL/TLS session.
D [19/Feb/2020:12:43:18 +0100] [Client 29] Connection now encrypted.
d [19/Feb/2020:12:43:18 +0100] [Client 29] cupsdReadClient: error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_STATE_WAITING, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODING_LENGTH, data_remaining=0, request=(nil)(), file=-1
D [19/Feb/2020:12:43:18 +0100] [Client 29] POST /printers/PDF HTTP/1.1
D [19/Feb/2020:12:43:18 +0100] [Client 29] Read: status=200, state=6
d [19/Feb/2020:12:43:18 +0100] [Client 29] con->uri="/printers/PDF", con->best=0x55dfb097b7b0(/printers)
D [19/Feb/2020:12:43:18 +0100] [Client 29] No authentication data provided.
D [19/Feb/2020:12:43:18 +0100] [Client 29] 1.0 Get-Printer-Attributes 11
D [19/Feb/2020:12:43:18 +0100] [Client 29] Returning IPP successful-ok for Get-Printer-Attributes (https://example.com:632/printers/PDF) from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.
D [19/Feb/2020:12:43:18 +0100] [Client 29] Content-Length: 9508
D [19/Feb/2020:12:43:18 +0100] [Client 29] cupsdSendHeader: code=200, type="application/ipp", auth_type=0
D [19/Feb/2020:12:43:18 +0100] [Client 29] con->http=0x55dfb0b445a0
D [19/Feb/2020:12:43:18 +0100] [Client 29] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_STATE_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODING_LENGTH, data_remaining=9508, response=0x55dfb0b549c0(IPP_STATE_DATA), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
D [19/Feb/2020:12:43:18 +0100] [Client 29] Writing IPP response, ipp_state=IPP_STATE_DATA, old wused=0, new wused=0
D [19/Feb/2020:12:43:18 +0100] [Client 29] bytes=0, http_state=0, data_remaining=9508
D [19/Feb/2020:12:43:18 +0100] [Client 29] Flushing write buffer.
D [19/Feb/2020:12:43:18 +0100] [Client 29] New state is HTTP_STATE_WAITING
D [19/Feb/2020:12:43:18 +0100] [Client 29] Waiting for request.
d [19/Feb/2020:12:43:18 +0100] [Client 29] cupsdReadClient: error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_STATE_WAITING, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODING_LENGTH, data_remaining=0, request=(nil)(), file=-1
D [19/Feb/2020:12:43:18 +0100] [Client 29] POST /printers/PDF HTTP/1.1
D [19/Feb/2020:12:43:18 +0100] [Client 29] Read: status=200, state=6
d [19/Feb/2020:12:43:18 +0100] [Client 29] con->uri="/printers/PDF", con->best=0x55dfb097b7b0(/printers)
D [19/Feb/2020:12:43:18 +0100] [Client 29] No authentication data provided.
D [19/Feb/2020:12:43:18 +0100] [Client 29] 1.0 Get-Printer-Attributes 11
D [19/Feb/2020:12:43:18 +0100] [Client 29] Returning IPP successful-ok for Get-Printer-Attributes (https://example.com:632/printers/PDF) from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.
D [19/Feb/2020:12:43:18 +0100] [Client 29] Content-Length: 9508
D [19/Feb/2020:12:43:18 +0100] [Client 29] cupsdSendHeader: code=200, type="application/ipp", auth_type=0
D [19/Feb/2020:12:43:18 +0100] [Client 29] con->http=0x55dfb0b445a0
D [19/Feb/2020:12:43:18 +0100] [Client 29] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_STATE_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODING_LENGTH, data_remaining=9508, response=0x55dfb0b3bbb0(IPP_STATE_DATA), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
D [19/Feb/2020:12:43:18 +0100] [Client 29] Writing IPP response, ipp_state=IPP_STATE_DATA, old wused=0, new wused=0
D [19/Feb/2020:12:43:18 +0100] [Client 29] bytes=0, http_state=0, data_remaining=9508
D [19/Feb/2020:12:43:18 +0100] [Client 29] Flushing write buffer.
D [19/Feb/2020:12:43:18 +0100] [Client 29] New state is HTTP_STATE_WAITING
D [19/Feb/2020:12:43:18 +0100] [Client 29] Waiting for request.
d [19/Feb/2020:12:44:27 +0100] [Client 29] cupsdReadClient: error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_STATE_WAITING, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODING_LENGTH, data_remaining=0, request=(nil)(), file=-1
D [19/Feb/2020:12:44:27 +0100] [Client 29] HTTP_STATE_WAITING Closing for error 32 (Broken pipe)
D [19/Feb/2020:12:44:27 +0100] [Client 29] Closing connection.
D [19/Feb/2020:12:44:27 +0100] [Client 29] Waiting for socket close.
d [19/Feb/2020:12:44:27 +0100] [Client 29] cupsdReadClient: error=32, used=0, state=HTTP_STATE_WAITING, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODING_LENGTH, data_remaining=0, request=(nil)(), file=-1
D [19/Feb/2020:12:44:27 +0100] [Client 29] Closing on EOF.
D [19/Feb/2020:12:44:27 +0100] [Client 29] Closing connection.
```

**lpstat -v**

```
scheduler is running
no system default destination
device for PDF: tea4cups://
PDF accepting requests since Mi 20 Nov 2019 15:45:13 CET
printer PDF is idle.  enabled since Mi 20 Nov 2019 15:45:13 CET
```

**cupsd.conf**

```
LogLevel warn
PageLogFormat
MaxLogSize 0

# Allow remote access
Port 632

MaxClients 400
MaxClientsPerHost 80

# Share local printers on the local network.
Browsing On
BrowseLocalProtocols dnssd
BrowseWebIF No

DefaultAuthType Basic
DefaultEncryption Required

WebInterface No

HostNameLookups On

ServerName example.com

<Location />
AuthType None
Encryption Required
# Allow shared printing...
Order allow,deny
Allow all
</Location>
<Location /printers>
AuthType None
Encryption Required
Order allow,deny
Allow all
</Location>
<Location /admin>
AuthType Basic
Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM @print_admins
Order allow,deny
Allow all
</Location>
<Location /admin/conf>
AuthType Basic
Require user @SYSTEM @print_admins marc
Order allow,deny
Allow all
</Location>
<Location /admin/log>
AuthType Default
Require user @SYSTEM @print_admins marc
Order allow,deny
</Location>
<Policy authenticated>
  JobPrivateAccess default
  JobPrivateValues default
  SubscriptionPrivateAccess default
  SubscriptionPrivateValues default
  <Limit Create-Job Print-Job Print-URI Get-Notifications Send-Document Release-Job Validate-Job>
    AuthType Basic
    Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM @print_admins @print_users
    Order deny,allow
    Allow all
    Allow localhost
  </Limit>
  <Limit Send-URI Hold-Job Restart-Job Purge-Jobs Set-Job-Attributes Create-Job-Subscription Renew-Subscription Cancel-Subscription Reprocess-Job Cancel-Current-Job Suspend-Current-Job Resume-Job Cancel-My-Jobs Close-Job CUPS-Move-Job CUPS-Get-Document>
    AuthType Basic
    Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM @print_admins @print_users
    Order deny,allow
    Allow all
    Allow localhost
  </Limit>
  <Limit CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer CUPS-Delete-Printer CUPS-Add-Modify-Class CUPS-Delete-Class CUPS-Set-Default>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @SYSTEM @print_admins
    Order deny,allow
    Allow all
  </Limit>
  <Limit Pause-Printer Resume-Printer Enable-Printer Disable-Printer Pause-Printer-After-Current-Job Hold-New-Jobs Release-Held-New-Jobs Deactivate-Printer Activate-Printer Restart-Printer Shutdown-Printer Startup-Printer Promote-Job Schedule-Job-After Cancel-Jobs CUPS-Accept-Jobs CUPS-Reject-Jobs>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @SYSTEM @print_admins
    Order deny,allow
    Allow all
  </Limit>
  <Limit Cancel-Job CUPS-Authenticate-Job>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM @print_admins @print_users
    Order deny,allow
    Allow all
  </Limit>
  <Limit All>
    AuthType None
    Order deny,allow
    Allow all
  </Limit>
</Policy>
```

**printers.conf**

```
# Printer configuration file for CUPS v2.2.10
# Written by cupsd
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE WHEN CUPSD IS RUNNING
<Printer PDF>
UUID urn:uuid:bb8eef67-3503-1234-1234-1234546464
Info PDF
MakeModel Generic CUPS-PDF Printer (w/ options)
#DeviceURI cups-pdf:/
DeviceURI tea4cups://
State Idle
StateTime 1574261113
ConfigTime 1551802733
Type 12644428
Accepting Yes
Shared Yes
JobSheets none none
QuotaPeriod 0
PageLimit 0
KLimit 0
AllowUser @print_admins
AllowUser @print_users
OpPolicy authenticated
ErrorPolicy abort-job
</Printer>
```

Comment: What Linux distribution and version and what printer type do you use? What is the OS of the client? Does the client already have jobs in its print queue? Does your CUPS printer require authentication? Please [edit] your question to add information. If you tried solutions suggested somewhere else, please provide references to the non-working solutions. A google search found these hints: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=199882  https://forum.manjaro.org/t/printer-doesnt-work-closing-for-error-32-broken-pipe/40678  (and more)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. i added furth details. 
None of these links are of use as we use the same universal driver on all clients and it works on 49/50 machines. Most have the same OS (patched win 10) as the client that's making problems